# Minimize height of Xamarin.Forms Grid when text wraps in multiple columns

Tags: xamarin.forms

In HTML, when a table has multiple columns of text that can wrap, the browser calculates optimal columns widths to minimize the height of the table. For example, with the following HTML, as you can see in [its fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/breyed/ad1k1ef4/), the first column will be a little wider than the second. Exactly how much depends on the font details.

```html
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy lazy lazy dog</td>
    <td>The lazy brown fox jumped over the dog</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Android's TableLayout supports this with shrinkable columns. With Xamarin.Forms Grid, however, this doesn't seem to be possible. You can force a proportion with Star, but it isn't dynamic based on the column contents. Setting a column to Auto doesn't help; it will take up the full available width, without sharing that width with columns that come after it.

Is there a way to get Grid or any other control to share column widths so as to minimize the overall height?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is unfortunately no. Xamarin Forms grid isn't based on any platform control, its just setting elements locations based on its own calculations in GridCalc.cs.

The Grid only supports Star, Auto and GridLength.

- Star = Splits the screen in equal portions
- Auto = Matches contents
- GridLength = Specifies the exact height or width

The best option might be to set your second column as a defined width, then your first column will shrink and grow with screen size.

Comment: The problem with a fixed width in either column is that it can lead to unnatural looking gaps if the text doesn't use much space. A reasonable workaround for my use cases would be if you can set a star-based max width. For example, if the second column were star, but the first column were auto, but a max of star. It's easy to compute, but I don't know if there's any way to add the functionality.

Comment: If you set an auto, it uses all the space needed, then the stars just split up the remaining space. The only way to do this, would be to calculate the width of the screen itself, calculate the width of the text, and manually set the grid widths. The Grid doesn't have anything like Shrinkable columns, built-in.